# XText: ambiguous grammar with identifiers

Tags: xtext, ambiguous-grammar

I am having a problem with an ambiguous Xtext grammar, but I just cannot find the correct solution.

```
Program: (statements+=Statement)+
Statement: (AssignmentStatement | ResetStatement);
ResetStatement returns Statement:
  'RESET' (fields+=Identifier)+
;

AssignStatement returns Statement:
  target=Identifier ':=' object=Identifier
;
```

The problem I get is that the RESET statement may have several fields to RESET; however, when a ':=' token is located, the parser should detect the beginning of an AssignmentStatement instead. I have tried using syntactic predicates, but I was only able to disambiguate the grammar doing:

```
ResetStatement returns Statement:
  'RESET' =>(fields+=Identifier)+
;
```

However, as you might notice that is not the expected behavior, as:

```
RESET ID1 ID2
ID3 := ID1
```

Returns an error at the ':=' token. I tried adding the predicate marker to the AssignmentStatement:

```
Statement: (=>AssignmentStatement | ResetStatement);
```

And also:

```
AssignStatement returns Statement:
  =>(target=Identifier ':=') object=Identifier
;
```

But with no success. The error is in all the cases:

```
[fatal] rule ruleResetStatement has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,2.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.
```

I am quite lost so any hints are well appreciated.

Comment: Please post the entire grammar and the error message - the snippet given is not ambiguous so far.

Comment: I am sorry, when I wrote the question I didn't realize I had forgotten the program specification rule, which is the one causing the ambiguity. I also added the ANTLR error reported by Xtext.

Comment: How does your rule Identifier look like?

Comment: The Identifier rule holds a reference to a Variable; which in turn has two fields referencing terminals

Comment: The given information is not sufficient to reproduce an ambiguity. Please attach the entire grammar..